# replace random missing data in place using another file

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have multiple csv files with some randomly missing rows. I want to find the file with the longest length and put it as a reference to replace the missing data of the other files so that it does not simply pad to the end of the column. I want to use the longest column B, which is time, to set as the reference column and check if the other file has all the rows of the long B if not add a new row, a value for A from the previous row, and get B value from the reference column then shift the rest of the rows one row down, to match with the reference file, for each substitution. I have these dummy files as below but the output pad the missing data to the end of the column as below, in which df1.B has 11 and 13 missing I want to bring 11 as the second row of B and 1 as the second row of A and shift the rest down

Here is what I tried:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a list of DataFrames
dataframes = []
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [10, 12, 14]})
df1.columns = [f"A_{len(dataframes) + 1}", f"B_{len(dataframes) + 1}"]
dataframes.append(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [7, 8, 9, 10], 'B': [10, 11, 12, 13]})
df2.columns = [f"A_{len(dataframes) + 1}", f"B_{len(dataframes) + 1}"]
dataframes.append(df2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [7, 8, 9, 10, 11], 'B': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]})
df3.columns = [f"A_{len(dataframes) + 1}", f"B_{len(dataframes) + 1}"]
dataframes.append(df3)

# Get the longest DataFrame
longest_index = max(range(len(dataframes)), key=lambda i: len(dataframes[i]))
longest_df = dataframes[longest_index]

# Concatenate the DataFrames and reindex with the longest DataFrame's columns
merged_df = pd.concat(dataframes, axis=1, join='outer')

for col in merged_df.columns:
    merged_df[col] = merged_df[col].fillna(method='ffill')

print(merged_df)
```

output:

```
A_1   B_1   A_2   B_2  A_3  B_3
0  1.0  10.0   7.0  10.0    7   10
1  2.0  12.0   8.0  11.0    8   11
2  3.0  14.0   9.0  12.0    9   12
3  3.0  14.0  10.0  13.0   10   13
4  3.0  14.0  10.0  13.0   11   14
```

but what I want to get is:

```
   A_1   B_1   A_2   B_2  A_3  B_3
0  1.0  10.0   7.0  10.0    7   10
1  1.0  11.0   8.0  11.0    8   11
2  2.0  12.0   9.0  12.0    9   12
3  2.0  13.0  10.0  13.0   10   13
4  3.0  14.0  10.0  13.0   11   14
```

Can someone please help me with this,
thank you